# Remove privilege enum flags the right way in C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, enums

I have an enum type for user privileges that looks like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum UserPrivileges : byte
{
    None = 0,                                     // 0000 0000
    View = 1 << 0,                                // 0000 0001
    Import = 1 << 1,                              // 0000 0010
    Export = 1 << 2,                              // 0000 0100
    Supervisor = View | Import | Export | 1 << 3, // 0000 1111
    Admin = Supervisor | 1 << 4                   // 0001 1111
}
```

These values are bound to CheckBoxes in the GUI with a value converter. (I wanted to do this as generic as possible because there are also different privileges [e.g. EmployeePrivileges])

```
public class ByteFlagsEnumValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private byte _targetValue;

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                          object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var mask = (byte)parameter;
        _targetValue = (byte)value;
        return ((mask | _targetValue) == _targetValue);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var mask = (byte)parameter;

        if ((bool)value)
        {
            _targetValue |= mask;
        }
        else
        {
            // Get next superflag for mask (e.g. 0110 -> 1111)
            var b = mask;
            b--;
            b |= (byte)(b >> 1);
            b |= (byte)(b >> 2);
            b |= (byte)(b >> 4);
            b |= (byte)(b >> 8);

            // if you remove a superflag (e.g. 1111) also remove
            // everything higher than this flag
            if (mask == b || mask == 1)
                _targetValue &= (byte)(mask >> 1);
            else
                // ????????
        }

        return Enum.Parse(targetType, _targetValue.ToString());
    }
}
```

This works really fine for displaying and adding privileges to the user in the GUI. Also it works for removing Superflags like Supervisor (all flags `>=` Supervisor get removed, the other flags don't change).

The problem is when I uncheck Import for example, I want to remove all Superflags (Supervisor, Admin) but would like to keep the other flags (View, Export).

```
0001 1111 // Admin
0000 0010 // Import
---------
0000 0101 // View | Export
```

But I haven't come up with an good idea how to accomplish this. Anyboy who has a good solution for this?

Comment: Are you trying to avoid using conditional logic? If you start coding this with if/else statements, it's pretty straight forward.

Comment: In your example - you like to remove `Admin` and `Import` ?

Comment: @Candide I want to keep this as generic as possible, so I could use this also for other projects or different privileges.

Comment: IMHO, you are abusing enums here which is causing you all the trouble.

Comment: @Mzf in my example I want to remove Import and therefore also Admin and Supervisor should be removed

Comment: @DanielHilgarth what would you use? Because I think using flags (no matter if enum or int or whatever) is ideal for this, because you only need one field to represent multiple privileges and can easily get if a user has a specific privilege with .HasFlag(...)

Comment: @Staeff: Yeah, but the problem here is that you are trying to encode logic *into* the enum.

Comment: I think, the problem is related to the definition of the enum, that mixes privileges (View, Import, Export) with roles (Supervisor, Admin).

Comment: @Staeff I think my answer is the one you want. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Mfz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474569/mzf) brought me on the right way but, it wasn't generic enough for me, so I came up with another solution:

```
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
                              object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var mask = (byte)parameter;

        if ((bool)value)
        {
            _targetValue |= mask;
        }
        else
        {
            if (IsSuperFlag(mask) && mask != 1)
                _targetValue &= (byte)(mask >> 1);
            else
            {
                // Get all flags from enum type that are no SuperFlags
                var flags = Enum.GetValues(targetType).Cast<Enum>();
                flags = flags.Where(x => !IsSuperFlag(System.Convert.ToByte(x)));

                long nonSuperFlags = 0;

                foreach (var flag in flags)
                {
                    nonSuperFlags |= System.Convert.ToByte(flag);
                }

                // Now only remove everything except the nonSuperFlags
                // and then remove the mask
                _targetValue &= (byte)(~(_targetValue ^ nonSuperFlags | mask));

            }
        }

        return Enum.Parse(targetType, _targetValue.ToString());
    }

    private bool IsSuperFlag(byte flag)
    {
        var b = flag;
        b--;
        b |= (byte)(b >> 1);
        b |= (byte)(b >> 2);
        b |= (byte)(b >> 4);
        b |= (byte)(b >> 8);

        return b == flag;
    }
```

I simply got all non superflags for the enum type and them removed only the superflags and afterwards removed the flag.

Comment: It is very far from the best way. But since you accomplish your goal that is the matter.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you want , this should do the job

```
    byte tmp = 1 << 3 | 1 << 4;
    byte removeSuperFlagMask = (byte) (~tmp);

    byte notSuperflagsMask = 1 << 3 | 1 << 2 | 1 << 1;
    if ((valueToRemove & notSuperflagsMask) != 0)
    {
        newValue = (byte)(removeSuperFlagMask & currentValue & ~valueToRemove);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for bringing me to the idea, but I needed a more generic solution. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to remove `Supervisor` and `Admin` so:

```
UserPrivileges newPrivileges = (UserPrivileges)(((byte)currentPrivileges) & 7;
```

It will perform like this:

```
0001 1111 // Admin
0000 0111 // 7 flag
---------
0000 0111 // Remain only where 7 bit was set.
```

Another example

```
0000 0011 // View | Import
0000 0111 // 7 flag
---------
0000 0011 // Remain only where 7 bit was set.
```

By remain I mean that where `7` flag is set it will persist the value in the result (beein `0` or `1`). And where the `7` flag is `0` it will kill the value to `0`.